# Scroll down method in mobile karate fw

Tags: mobile, frameworks, karate

There is a scroll down method for Web UI test in the Karate framework, but it does not work in the mobile framework. Can you let us know how we use the scroll down function in the mobile karate framework?

Thanks in advance

Comment: is it on mobile web or iOS or android?

Comment: app works within both Android and iOS. Without a scroll down, it is impossible to go down and test elements that are bottom of the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try an alternative option like [mobile command](https://appium.io/docs/en/commands/mobile-command/) with `driver.script()`

eg:

```
driver.script("mobile: scroll", { "direction" : "down"})
```

for iOS refer to: https://github.com/appium/appium-xcuitest-driver#mobile-scroll

for android refer to: https://github.com/appium/appium-uiautomator2-driver#mobile-scroll

incase you need `elementId` try:

```
def locatorElementId = driver.elementId('<locator>')
```

Comment: Hi Babu,
I have tried to make "scroll down" by using "driver.script("mobile: scroll", { "direction" : "down"})" as you suggested. However, It does not work. Can you share if you have example or best practice?

Comment: In addition above,  I have below error message;
 js failed:
01: driver.script("mobile: scroll", { "direction" : "down"})
org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: class net.minidev.json.JSONObject cannot be cast to class java.lang.String (net.minidev.json.JSONObject is in unnamed module of loader 'app'; java.lang.String is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
- com.intuit.karate.driver.WebDriver.isJavaScriptError(WebDriver.java:129)
- com.intuit.karate.driver.WebDriver.eval(WebDriver.java:155)
- com.intuit.karate.driver.appium.AppiumDriver.script(AppiumDriver.java:174)

Comment: @EmrahBulut can you follow the process https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: Thanks Babu,
It works well if we use the script as below;

And driver.script("mobile: scroll", { "strategy" : "accessibility id", "selector": "Lists"})
"Lists" is here its locator
The only restriction is using limited selector support with this scroll.

Android you can only use: accessibility id, class name, -android uiautomator
iOS you can only use: predicateString

Comment: yes for future reference : https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/1686